# Wamp is not opening

Tags: wamp

I have installed wamp version 2.5 for a 64 bit and i am getting an error of a missing msvcr110.dll file. When I downloaded it and put in in SysWow64 folder, the error changed into another error. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: I think the problem is you manually downloaded the dll. Use the links on the document Fernando pointed you to, and download and INSTALL all the runtimes properly. A copy into whatever folder is not installing it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest version of Microsoft C/C++ resditributables installed?

The 2008 redistributable is used by wampmanager.exe, the 2010 redistributable is used by some versions of Apache & MySQL and the 2012 redistributable is used by some versions of Apache & MySQL.

[Here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123608) you can find a full requirements list.